# Is it valid to have undo steps that only move point?

Tags: undo

Recently I found a package `vundo` has a [bug](https://github.com/casouri/vundo/issues/14) with undo steps that only move point (cursor).

This only happens rarely and I'm not sure how to re-create this situation.
Although this works with emacs undo without problems.

This leads me to the question, is it valid to have undo steps that only position point? Or might this be considered a bug - which should be resolved by ensuring the undo data is never allowed to store these values?

---

Note: I have undo amalgamation disabled:  `(fset 'undo-auto-amalgamate 'ignore)` which could be why I'm running into this issue.

Note: this has been asked on the [developer mailing list](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2022-03/msg00766.html).

Comment: The question is vague and opinion-based. What *"should"* `undo` do? Bring that up in Emacs mailing list `emacs-devel`, if you like. Here, you could ask something about what `undo` actually does. As for what some other, 3rd-party "undo such as `vundo`, what it "should" do is even more problematic. Ask its maintainers about that.

Comment: Inasmuch as the `buffer-undo-list` is *a list* which can be navigated to the desired element, there may not be any need to to prevent certain elements from being inserted into the list ... i.e., let undo do what it is supposed to do and build a package that does something with the list.  See also how amalgamation is handled and consider adjusting that function to handle a certain set of undo events based on defined criteria, rather than `amalgamating-undo-limit` -- see the function `undo-auto-amalgamate` and how it is used.

Comment: I'm wondering if this might be an X-Y problem, where the real issue is that point movement is erroneously being allowed to take effect instead of being hidden in a `save-excursion` form or similar.

Comment: I have disabled `undo-auto-amalgamate`, so my concern is the state of `buffer-undo-list` being valid or not. If it's invalid then the issue is tracking down how this happens. If it's valid, all tools that operate on undo data should support them.